# Check for null condition for left side table in left join in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

I am using left join in linq query. I need to check the left table value is null or not in the ON clause.

```
   join x in employeee on u.id equals x.userId into ux 
   from ujoinx in ux.DefaultIfEmpty()
   join y in department on ujoinx.id equals y.employeeId into xy 
   from xjoiny in xy.DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new {
      EmployeeSal = ujoinx!=null?ujoinx.employeeSal:0, 
      EmployeeTax = ujoinx!=null?ujoinx.employeeTax:0, 
      UserName = u.username,
      DeptName = xjoiny!=null?xjoiny.name:""         
   }
```

Here I want to check **ujoinx** is not null in this join condition. `join y in department on ujoinx.id equals y.employeeId into xy`.

Is there any possibility to check the null condition with `ujoinx.id equals y.employeeId`?

Comment: Why don't you add a where clause before doing the join?

Comment: I tried ```join y in department where ujoinx != null on ujoinx.id equals y.employeeId into xy ``` . It is not working

Comment: Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In your comment, you placed the `where` clause in the wrong spot.  You should filter *before* the `join`:

```
from ujoinx in ux.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where ujoinx != null
    join y in department on ujoinx.id equals y.employeeId
    into xy
```